# Referencing a model from a string

Tags: php, class, methods, model, radix

How can I call the model from a string?

```
$model = 'User';
```

I tried the following:

```
\App\.$model::get();
\App\{$model}::get();
\App\.{$model}::get();
\App\${$model}::get();
\App\.${$model}::get();
```

I feel like I'm missing something although a workaround it would be:

```
$model = 'App\User';
$model::get();
```

But for learning purposes im trying to see how i can mix it up like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a string out of the whole thing:

```
namespace App;

class Model {
    public static function go() {
        echo 'yay!';
    }
}

$someString = 'Model';
$className = 'App\\' . $someString;
var_dump(new $className());
$className::go();
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/78VkL).